# Manage automation via ampscript API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript

Is there a way to start an automation via **AMPScript API** within a landing page?

I tried the following and it throws an error that the automation is **deleted**

.  However, the automation is **not deleted**.

```
%%[

   SET @automation = CreateObject("Automation")

   SetObjectProperty(@automation , "CustomerKey", "CT_Offers")

   SET @auto_statusCode = InvokePerform(@automation, "start", @errorCode)  

]%%
```

Comment: Could you get this AMPScript working? I have using the same with ObjectID but it throws an error

Comment: Please see my updated results on this topic here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377504/guide-to-trigger-automation-via-ampscript

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform an Automation object, it requires passing in the ObjectID instead of the CustomerKey.  If you need to get the ObjectID then InvokeRetrieve can be used.

With Retrieve, it is kind of odd because the property that has to be specified is "ProgramID" even though in the response it is called "ObjectID". Basically 2 names for the same field just depends on the context as to which it wants.

Comment: Is this on the help wiki somewhere?  If not, it should be.

Comment: For Automations created in the UI, you can also put in a call to Global Support and they can retrieve for you if you would rather avoid creating the InvokeRetrieve block.

Comment: Please see my updated results on this topic here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377504/guide-to-trigger-automation-via-ampscript