# SSJS InvokePerform Query Definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs

The status for this InvokePerform is coming back as undefined. Any ideas what is wrong with my code?

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    var QD_ExternalKey = "d9868a1f-875d-4723-b0bb-14b5b514a671";

    var APIObject = Platform.Function.CreateObject("QueryDefinition");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(APIObject, "CustomerKey", QD_ExternalKey);

    var newObject = Platform.Function.InvokePerform(APIObject, "Start", StatusAndRequestID, Options);
    var statusMessage = StatusAndRequestID[0];
    var errorCode = StatusAndRequestID[1];
    var performResponse = StatusAndRequestID[2];

</script>

statusMessage: <ctrl:var name=statusMessage />
errorCode: <ctrl:var name=errorCode />
performResponse: <ctrl:var name=performResponse />
```

**Output:**
statusMessage: undefined

errorCode: undefined

performResponse: undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform, InvokePerform an QueryDefinition object, it requires passing in the `ObjectID` instead of the CustomerKey. If you need to get the ObjectID then InvokeRetrieve can be used.

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    var APIObject = Platform.Function.CreateObject("QueryDefinition");     
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(APIObject, "ObjectID", "Your ObjectID here");   
    var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0,0];
    var newObject = Platform.Function.InvokePerform(APIObject, "Start", StatusAndRequestID,Options);

    var statusMessage = StatusAndRequestID[0];
    var errorCode = StatusAndRequestID[1];
    var performResponse = StatusAndRequestID[2];

</script>

statusMessage: <ctrl:var name=statusMessage /> 
errorCode: <ctrl:var name=errorCode /> 
performResponse: <ctrl:var name=performResponse />
```

**Output:**
statusMessage: QueryDefinition perform called successfully 
errorCode: 0 
performResponse: {JSON Response}

Related Post: [Manage automation via ampscript API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80022/manage-automation-via-ampscript-api)

Comment: Great, thank you! I had to use an InvokeRetrieve() to obtain the ObjectID value for my query definition.