# how to trigger an automation right at the same time when a record is added in a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, automation

how to trigger an automation right at the same time when a record is added in a data extension?

Right now i have data extract and file transfer setup with automation but the problem is, automation for data extra itself can only be configured minimum of 1 hour based on automation.

But I would like to trigger the automation as soon as a record is added in a data extension. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If the record is added to the data extension through another API-based process (such as a landing page, or a client you created), you can try adding an additional call to execute your automation.

[**Interaction with Automation Studio via the Web Service SOAP API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm)

You can make the same request in AMPscript using InvokePerform(). Here's an example:

[**Manage Automation via AMPScript API**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80022/manage-automation-via-ampscript-api)

Comment: You might want to handle errors with this call as if the automation is already running when it is called, it will fail

Comment: I do not have an option to trigger anything by API as i am not working with API.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? Can I trigger a query when new record is added and that query can trigger the automation?

Comment: Can I use activities to trigger my automation?

Comment: @kuml The script (aka SSJS) activity in Automation Studio can be used to execute another automation, by API.